# How to negate connected verbs which in て-form?

Tags: verbs, て-form, negation

As I know if I connect verbs with て-form then the last verb determine the tense, politeness. But how can I negate the sentence? Should I just negate the last verb or should I negate the verb which in the て-form? And if I shoud negate て-form which negation use: なくて or ないで?

For example, how to negate this sentence?

```
こうえん に いって、とり を みる。- I will go to the park and I will see the birds.
```

Maybe:

```
1, こうえん に いって、とり を  みない。
```

or

```
2, こうえん に いかなくて、 とり を みない。
```

or

```
3, こうえん に いかないで、 とり を みない。
```

?

So I want to achive this: I won't go to the park and I won't see the birds.

Comment: [this](https://www.kanshudo.com/grammar/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%83%BB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6%E3%83%BB%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB) looks helpful

Comment: Not sure which you mean (so I won't edit), but 「とり」 is "bird"; 「とりい」 is a shrine gate/archway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I spend more time with this question and read lots of article and watched few videos I found the answer.
So て-form has many usage, but we are only interested in the connecting fuction which has the following cases:

- **expressing the chronological order of actions:** in this case we just connecting/linking verbs in chronological order, but no logical connection between them.

  [ do A action after that do B action ]

  For example:

  > こうえん に いって、とり を みる。- I will go to the park and (after that) I will see the birds.

  The A action: I will go, B action: I will see

  > マンガ を よんで テレビ を みた。- I read manga and (after that) watched TV.

  negative form: なくて

  For example:

  > こうえん に いかなくて、 とり を みない。- I won't go to the park and (after that) I won't see the birds.

  > マンガ を よまなくて テレビ を みなかった。- I didn't read manga and (after that) didn't watch TV.

  I think it is possible and correct negate the last verb:

  > こうえん に いって、とり を みなかった。- I went to the park and I didn't see the birds.

  But I don't think to negate only the first verb would be correct.
- **expressing the reason of action by/with action:** there is a causal relationship (logical connection) between actions when connect them

  [ do A action that's why do B action ]

  For emxaple:

  > こうえん に いって、とり を みた。- I went to the park so I saw the birds.

  I think we can interpret this sentence in this way too, because maybe I can't see birds on other place so I have to go to the park to see them.

  negative form: なくて

  For emxaple:

  > こうえん に いかなくて、えいがかん に いった。- I didn't go to the park so I went to the cinema.

  As we see it is possible and correct negate only one verb (no matter which one)
- **expressing the means of the action by/with action:** in this case the actions overlapping each other. So an action express how to do another action.

  [ do B action by/with A action ]

  For example:

  > はしって えき に いった。- I went to the station by running.

  negative form: ないで or ずに

  For example:

  > はしらないで えき に いった。- I went to the station without running.

  As we see it is possible and correct negate only one verb (no matter which one) in this case too.

Of course we can use て-form connecting not just verbs, but:

- **we can connect clauses**, in this case the negative form: なくて

  For example:

  > それ は ペン じゃなくて えんぴつ です。- That isn't pen, but pencil.

Source:

[tofugu.com](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-te-form-linking/), [japanistry.com](https://www.japanistry.com/the-te-form/), [Eric's Nihongo Lessons #1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVuW4X2At-w), [Eric's Nihongo Lessons #2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSXk4cj-nRs), [imabi.net](https://www.imabi.net/theparticlete.htm)

If there is no objection I will accept my own answer in within few days.